# retrieve information and select information popup in another page

Tags: php

This is the code of `search.php`: (this part I will search the keyword and display into `retrievecustomerinfo.php`)

```
<?php
 $strKeyword = NULL;
?>

<body>
<div align="center">
<form name="frmSearch" method="post" action="retrievecustomerinfo.php">
    <table >
        <tr>
            <th>Keyword
                <input name="txtKeyword" type="text" id="txtKeyword" value="<?php echo $strKeyword; ?>">
                <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </th>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

This is the code of `retrievecustomerinfo.php`: (this page will show the result what user need the information.)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);

$strKeyword = NULL;

if (isset($_POST["txtKeyword"])) {
    $strKeyword = $_POST["txtKeyword"];
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE cust_ic LIKE '%" . $strKeyword . "%' OR cust_hp_contact1 LIKE '%" . $strKeyword ."%' OR cust_name LIKE '%" . $strKeyword . "%' limit {$start} , {$perpage}";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
<form name="retrieve" action="topuppage.php" method="post">
<table class="table table-hover" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Contact Number</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php
    $no = 1;
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $no ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['cust_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['cust_state'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $result['cust_hp_contact1'] ?>
                <?php echo $result['cust_hp_contact2'] ?></td> 
            <td>
                <button type="submit" name="cust_name" value="<?php echo $result['cust_name'] ;?>"   
                        name="cust_hp_contact1" value="<?php echo $result['cust_hp_contact1'] ;?>" class="btn btn-link">SELECT</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $no++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
<?php
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This is code of `topuppage`: (this page will show value that user selected in `retrievecustomerinfo.php`)

```
<form name="getdata" method="get">
<div>

    <h5>TAG THIS SALE ORDER TO THE FOLLOWING CUSTOMER</h5>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <label for="cname">Contact Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cname" 
               value="
                   <?php 
                   if(isset($_POST['cust_name'])) 
                       { 
                       echo $_POST['cust_name']; 

                       } 
                       ?> ">



        <label for="cno">Contact Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cno" 
               value="
                   <?php 
                   if(isset($_POST['cust_hp_contact1'])) 
                       { 
                       echo $_POST['cust_hp_contact1']; 

                       } 
                       ?> ">
        <p></p>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
    </div>

</div>
</form>
```

How to get value from `retrievecustomerinfo.php` and post into `topuppage.php` 's textbox should be contact name and contact number?

Answer (score 0):

In your code change this line in retrievecustomerinfo.php: where i am adding radio button before cust_name. So that when user submits we get the post value in topuppage.php

```
<td><input type="radio" name="cust_name" value="<?php echo $result['cust_name'] ?>" /><?php echo $result['cust_name'] ?></td>
```

AND

In topuppage.php Change this line (where I had changed this `value="<?php if(isset($_POST['cust_name'])) { echo $_POST['cust_name']; } ?>"`)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['cust_name'])) { echo $_POST['cust_name']; } ?>">
```

Similarly do for contact number.

Comment: this output I have click i get this result :i.gyazo.com/455468f3b83bee81d5c2766d711c72b2.png

Comment: did you added this line `<input type="radio" name="cust_name" value="<?php echo $result['cust_name'] ?>" />` the radio button should have element-name `name="cust_name" ` AND than submit the form

Comment: yes I am, result is can pop up in textbox but got error before retrieve data.

Comment: if i remove the textbox will show me:
Contact Name value="
Notice: Undefined index: cust_name in C:\xampp\htdocs\fimosproject\topupmaxis.php on line 52
" Contact Number

Comment: It's a different file: `topupmaxis.php` instead of `topuppage.php`

Comment: and what is the code at your line number 52 -  \fimosproject\topupmaxis.php on line 52. please paste it as it is here..... And are you accessing this page without submitting the form at retrievecustomerinfo.php? If so than there is a probability that you will get an error of undefined index.

Comment: Edit that line like this `<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['cust_name'])) { echo $_POST['cust_name']; } ?>">`  to avoid throwing error when form is not submitted

Comment: I tried to modified your code. i have get result in the same row in textbox contact name only.. I will try again.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `retrievecustomerinfo.php` just add the value and name attribute to the submit button:

```
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['cust_name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['cust_state'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['cust_hp_contact1'] ?>
            <?php echo $result['cust_hp_contact2'] ?></td> 
        <td>
            <button type="submit" name="cust_name" value="<?php echo $result['cust_name'] ?>" class="btn btn-link">SELECT</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $no++;
}
```

And get the $_POST value in `topuppage.php`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="cname" value="<?php echo $_POST['cust_name']; ?>">
```

Comment: this output I have click i get this result :https://i.gyazo.com/455468f3b83bee81d5c2766d711c72b2.png